# Fluent interface configuration with lambdas in C#

Tags: c#, configuration, lambda, design-patterns

Many open source projects use a Configuration class and lambda's to clarify configuring a complex object. Take [Mass Transit](http://readthedocs.org/docs/masstransit/en/develop/index.html) for example. A simple configuration would be like so.

```
Bus.Initialize(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            sbc.VerifyMsDtcConfiguration();
            sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/test");
        });
```

When you hover over `Initialize` in Visual Studio it says the parameter for the method call is `Action<ServiceBusConfigurator>`. I was wondering if anyone could show a simple example of how to use this pattern on a class. I don't even know what to call this type of pattern and my "GoogleFu" is not working as of yet. In this particular case I realize the method is operating on a singleton pattern. But I am ok with it being an instance method on a class.

Comment: As a side note, naming conventions in that project are pretty non-standard. For example, interface names don't start with "I", probably in order to make the library seem more fluent.

Comment: For future reference, this pattern is called [Nested Closure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291514.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `Action<ServiceBusConfigurator>` is a method which accepts a single parameter of type `ServiceBusConfigurator`, does an "action" operating on that instance, and returns nothing (`void`).

.NET BCL (starting from 3.5) comes with predefined generic delegate signatures: `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2>` (etc.) for methods which don't return a value, and `Func<Tresult>`, `Func<T, Tresult>` (etc.) for methods accepting zero of more parameters and returning a single result instance of type `Tresult`.

When you create a method which accepts a delegate, you allow callers of your method to pass more than just data parameters - your method actually delegates a part of responsibility to external code. In your case, `Bus.Initialize` creates an instance of `ServiceBusConfigurator` (`sbc`), and then calls the specified action with the `sbc` instance as the parameter.

This basically lets your method control the lifetime of the configuration class instance. It is up to the caller to fill in the details, but actual instance is provided by your class:

```
 // this is not actual mass transit source code
 public class BusCreator
 {
     public static IBus Initialize(Action<IConfiguration> action)
     {
         // create the config instance here
         IConfiguration config = CreateDefaultConfig();

         // let callers modify it
         action(config);

         // use the final version to build the result
         return config.Build()
     }
 }
```

The benefit is that your built instance (the imaginary `IBus` in this case) cannot be modified further. Configuration instance is only created shortly, passed to an external method, and then used to create an immutable final object:

```
 IBus result = BusCreator.Configure(cfg => cfg.BusType = BusType.MSMQ);
```

Two things to note in the line above:

1. The code inside the anonymous method is wrapped inside a delegate passed to the method. It is not executed until the `Configure` method actually calls it.
2. The `cfg` parameter is created by the `Configure` method and passed to the lambda. After the method returns, this object doesn't exist anymore (or is wrapped inside the resulting object).

Comment: Ahh. The part I was missing was that Initialize needed to create the type and then invoke the action on it. I have it now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To add to what others have said, this is an "entry point" into a [fluent interface](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html). The approach of using an Action callback to achieve this is a nice way of isolating the fluent interface in a way that is at the same time very extensible.

Comment: if your answer was combined with Groo's it would be the best because you actually told me **What** it was :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This resembles the Unit of Work pattern, which is commonly associated with transactions and persistence scenarios, but seems to fit to your example.

The following citation was taken from [Martin Fowler's definition of the pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html):

> A Unit of Work keeps track of everything you do during a business transaction that can affect the database. When you're done, it figures out everything that needs to be done to alter the database as a result of your work.

If you change *business transaction* for *initialization* and *database* for *configuration*, you can get a better idea of what's going on. Additionally, think of the action (the delegate in case) as an atomic operation: either the new configuration is fully applied, or the current configuration is kept unchanged.

As noted, the action itself doesn't explicitly touch `Bus`. Even without knowing the details of the involved classes, we can guess how this interaction occurs:

- The `ServiceBusConfigurator` may be read after the action is invoked, before the `Initializa()` method returns (most likely);
- `Bus` might implement/extend `ServiceBusConfigurator`, so that `Initialize()` can pass `this` as the argument of the invoked action (less likely);
- `Bus` may be static and visible to `ServiceBusConfigurator`, which in turn can change the configuration properties of `Bus` upon a call to `ReceiveFrom()` (extremely convoluted and, I hope, very unlikely).

These are some strategies that just popped up my mind right now. Many others may be suggested!

Comment: I understand why it's useful. My question is how can something of type `Action<ServiceBusConfigurator>` act on the Bus class and do work?